# Representing an order relation with a real-valued function

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

Let $\succeq$ be a relation on a set $X$. The function $u: X\to \mathbb{R}$ *represents* the relation $\succeq$ if $x\succeq y \iff u(x)\geq u(y)$.

I am looking for a good reference on questions such as:

- What conditions on $\succeq$ guarantee that it can be represented by a function?
- What conditions guarantee that it can be represented by a certain kind of function, e.g, continuous, additive, etc.?
- When is the representing function unique (up to a certain transformation)?

These questions have been studied in economics, e.g, for representing an [ordinal utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility) relation by a [cardinal utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_utility) function. But since they are general mathematics questions, it is possible that they have also been studied in mathematics.

I found some papers presenting specific results of the kind I described above, but I am looking for a referene which summarizes the results in an orderly manner.

Comment: I have no references (sorry) but cannot resist to make a remark. It seems to me that you are looking at linear orders on partitions of $X$. Setting $[x]:=\{y\in X\mid u(y)=u(x)\}$ the partition is $\mathcal P:=\{[x]\mid x\in X\}$ and you can define relation $L$ on it by setting $[x]L[y]\iff u(x)\geq u(y)$. That makes $L$ a well defined reflexive linear order on $\mathcal P$.

Comment: So $\succ$ can be represented by a function if and only if $\succ$ is a linear order? This makes sense. Now the next questions are: what conditions on $\succ$ guarantee the existence of a representing function  $u$ with certain properties?

Comment: Necessary for the relation in your question to be represented as a function is: reflective, transitive and comparable. Then you are not yet dealing with a linear order but  a linear preorder. Antisymmetry lacks. The relation on $X$ induces a relation on the partition of $X$ that I mentioned in my former comment. There antisymmetry lacks no more so you have: reflective, transitive, comparable and antisymmetric (a reflexive linear order). I am only talking about necessity (not sufficiency), and have no real answer to the questions you pose. Good luck with your investigation.

Comment: An example of insufficiency is the lexicograpic ordering: http://economics.stackexchange.com/a/6892/385